# How to send data from timer task to android service

Tags: android, timertask

I am looking for a way to send data from my timer task to service. I have seen many other post related to handlers and all but I do not want to run in my main thread

Comment: what is the task you are doing?

Comment: understand your problem first and then post question here with all needed details.

Comment: I have a background service running always and updates are scheduled periodically. I have a timer task which connects to the server and gets the server time and then I need to pass that servertime from that timer task to my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write a singleton class which will hold data which you want to share. This is just a way not standard.

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                if (condition) {
                    MySingleton.getInstance().setData(put data here);
                } else {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 1000, 1000);
//then cancel timer somewhere by 
timer.cancel();
```

then in service you can get data by some thing like this

```
DataType myData = MySingleton.getInstance().getData();
```